# Struggling with subsection numbers in an article

Tags: sectioning, numbering, article

I am currently trying to number my sections and subsections in LaTeX as follows.

1 Section
1.1 Sub Section
1.1.1 Sub Sub Section,

however, seem to only be able to number my sections.

I am in the article class, and have put

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
```

within my preamble, but cannot seem to make it number correctly.

I'm still new to this, and so apologise if I haven't given enough detail.

My preamble is this

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,prl,nobalancelastpage,aps,10pt]{article}
%\documentclass[rmp,preprint]{revtex4-1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\usepackage{graphicx,bm,times}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage{appendix}
\def\bibsection{\section*{\refname}} 
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{#1#2#3\hrulefill}
\captionsetup[figure]{format=myformat}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-8em}
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Motivation behind the work}

\end{document}
```

My section Introduction is numbered 1, and then the subsection does not have the 1 number...

Comment: what you describe you want is the default behaviour, if you are getting something else you need to provide a complete small document that shows the problem. Add it to your question in a code block.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am a bit confused by what you mean to be my problem. Currently the only thing that is numbering is the sections, not the subsections and below. All I want to do it make my subsections also be numbered. I have added my preamble as this may help?

Comment: you still have not  posted any code that allows anyone to see your problem.  add \section{foo}\subsection{xxx}\end{document}` preferably removing all th epackages not required to show the problem

Comment: I kept your example but finished of the document but it produces numbered subsections [as seen in this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqTRx.png)

Comment: please edit the example to show subsections without numbers. If you are not getting numbers it is due to code that you have not shown, so it is hard to help.

Comment: I tried your MWE with added `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` headings. All were numbered and appeared in the ToC which I had also added by `\tableofcontents`. Your MWE did produce some warnings which were irrevelant to your problem. Please provide an MWE that actually shows your problem.

Comment: I have added how I have been writing my subsections and sections and have described what output I am getting now. I'm confused what other code it might be, if you can let me know what kind of thing you need me to add I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: For me, it works correctly your code. I don't know what could be wrong. Give more detailed information about your problem.

Comment: I don't know what more information I can give. I have the code set up right but am not getting subsection numbers.